# Xcode storyboard: How to fit different screen sizes with 10+ textfields

Tags: ios, swift, layout, autolayout, constraints

I've been working with a layout for now in pretty much +2 days. Watching multiple youtube videos, reading pretty much 50+ stack overflow threads, but I can't get my layout to fit different screen sizes.

I have a view inside another view. So the main-view is for the whole screen, and the subView is for half the screen. The problem is even if I set constraints and all of that, it don't auto-fit to different sizes, particularly not the labels/textfields.

Any idea on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood correctly you want the `second View` to be always the half of the `main View`.Because the main is the whole screen and its going to be half the screen.

If you want something like this

[image]

**Go to your storyboard**

- Add the `secondView`.
- Add equal height with the main View(ctrl drag to main view).
- 0 from right and top.
- Then make the width half of the main view.(Multiplier: 0.5)
  [image]
  [image]